# Swift или Swift+Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, apple

Что учить в 2019?Swift и Objective-C или только  Swift уже достаточно?

Comment: Учите все что можете выучить

Comment: Obj-c как базу все таки стоит изучить. После Swift база будет не полноценна как после Obj-c. Относительно работы, оч много проектов на поддержке на Obj-c. Не смотря на сложный синтаксис язык очень гибкий и после его изучения вы узнаете много тонкостей программирования. После Obj-c, Swift вам "залетит" на изи.

Comment: https://livetyping.com/ru/blog/na-chem-pishut-prilozhenija-pod-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря какая у Вас цель. Если для домашних проектов, то Swift достаточно. Если устроиться на работу в Сбербанк, то нужен Objective-C. Вообще, в мире еще много проектов на Objective-C, поэтому, если серьезно, то Objective-C все еще нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме Swift, учите так же Objective C. Многие компоненты внутри содержат Objective C, и надо понимать как он работает и как он устроен на глубоком уровне. Некоторые классы Swift это обертки над Objective C.

Банально - нажмите "Jump to Definition" на func viewDidLoad() и вы попадете в файл UIViewController.h, где на Objective C прописаны функции и свойства. Кроме этого, существует множество библиотек на Objective C, некоторых из которых нет на Swift. Конечно, использовать их в Swift вы все равно можете, но что-то исправить или добавить без знания языка уже не получится. Нередко справочная информация или примеры тоже бывают на Objective C, зная язык их несложно переписать на Swift.

Без Objective C вы не сможете подняться выше middle (а возможно и до него не сможете подняться).